# Cloud Spanner - Sharding based on String key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Our main goal is read performance as we typically do 80-90% reads to writes and I am trying to select the best primary key to achieve this goal.

The majority of our queries are based on customers e.g. get all products offered by customer X. Clients are identified by a three character string, similar to a ticker symbol.

My first thought is to create the primary key as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
    ProductId INT64 NOT NULL,
    CustomerCode STRING(3) NOT NULL,
    ...
) PRIMARY KEY (CustomerCode, ProductId);
```

My questions on this design are:

- How will Spanner shard data based on a string value?
- Will this approach create too many shards? We have about 100 key accounts and we are planning on using ~8 nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spanner does automatic load-based sharding of row ranges based on the primary key.

"Will this approach create too many shards?"

Unlike many other distributed databases, this isn't something you need to worry about. Since Cloud Spanner does dynamic load based sharding, it will automatically adjust up and down the number of serving shards based upon the load you place on the system. Row ranges that get more load will split into more shards and row ranges that get less load will automatically consolidate to fewer shards.

A good resource to read is [Optimizing Schema Design for Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/whitepapers/optimizing-schema-design).

Comment: This document recommends using a hashed key based on "ShardId = hash(key parts) % N" where N is the number of shards (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design#fix_hash_the_key). If Cloud Spanner handles all of the sharding under the hood, what is the benefit of specifying N and not just hashing the key parts?

Comment: Slightly different concept for shard - that is to give you a way to query monotonically changing data. E.g. you manually shard a time stamp into 5 'shards', then to get the newest time stamps you query those 5 'shards'. Using the hash without modulo N works fine for writing, it just doesn't give you an easy way to query the data using indexes.